# Custom ref style to a custom section?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I have issued

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Note \arabic{section}}
```

such that my sections

```
\section{Some title} \label{mysec}
```

appear as

> Note 1. Some title

Now when I cross-reference a section in the text

```
\ref{mysec}
```

it appears as

> Note 1

However, I would like for it to appear as

> Supplementary Note 1

when I reference it.

How can this be achieved (using standard packages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using package `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Note \arabic{section}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{Supplementary}{Supplementary}

\begin{document}

\section{Some title} \label{mysec}

\cref{mysec}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, I won't recommend you to redefine `\thesection`, since in this way `\subsection` would be shown as `Notes 1.1`, not just `1.1`. You can instead use `titlesec` to define the title format of `\section`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{Note~\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{Note~\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{Supplementary Note}{Supplementary Notes}

\begin{document}

\section{Some title} \label{mysec}

\subsection{test}

\cref{mysec}

\end{document}
```

[image]